# laravel 4 using a subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain

I am running laravel on a subdomain i.e. subdomain.mysite.com

I have setup my structure like this:

```
username
-public_html
--subdomain
---public
```

Basically, when I created my subdomain the path I set was `subname/public` so the subdomain points to the public folder. I have uploaded laravel to subname so when someone goes to the subdomain url it looks at the public folder and it shows the laravel You have arrived page.

Now when I browse to mysite.com/subname it gives me a forbidden page and when I browse to mysite.com/subname/public it shows the laravel you have arrive logo.

Is it safe to set-up laravel on a subdomain this way or am I exposing the app / model / controller folders etc?

Is this just very bad and should i move the laravel core files above public_html?

I hope this makes sense

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With proper Apache configuration (or any other server you use) and .htaccess ( in case of Apache) you can restrict the access to your core directories irrespective of where your files are located.

I do not know about your server configuration and which folders you have access to, but in case you have access to other directories, you can set up laravel in somewhere else other than under `public_html` and set up `public` directory to be visible, just like you did when setting up it as a sub-domain.

If you want to setup as a sub-folder under `mysite.com` you can keep the Laravel installation somewhere else, and provide symbolic link under `public_html` like this

```
ln -s /path/to/laravel/public /username/public_html/subdomain
```

In such case you need to add following line to .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /subdomain # Add this line

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Tharumax, so even though my laravel core files folder is within the public_html folder, it is still okay to have it there? When I browse to this folder on the normal domain it gives me a forbidden. Will this be okay?

Comment: As long as user cannot access the core files via web I think its OK. May be your `apache` config has `DirectoryIndex` disabled by default. Could you access the individual core `.php` files via Web? Like `mysite.com/subdomain/server.php`. If so additional config is needed.